# Electrum exchange rates. Where do they come from and why are they incorrect?

Tags: electrum

On the simple view on the Electrum client, the value of the bitcoins is displayed in USD, GBP and EUR (changeable by clicking on it).

Currently by clicking through, I am seeing exchange rates:

- 10.29GBP/BTC
- 10.40EUR/BTC
- 11.90USD/BTC

This is completely out of line with mtgox, and also completely out of line with international currency markets (currently 1.6usd/gbp and 1.24eur/gbp)

So could someone explain where these rates come from and why they are so incorrect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of this writing, Electrum [retrieves its exchange rate](https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/blob/9fc4e1a1b10a486d8c56d8c08f1d86d23dfd2e5e/lib/exchange_rate.py#L31) from [Intersango](https://intersango.com/). The last sale there must have been abnormally low for the current exchange rate.

Comment: In this forum post: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=100502.msg1308531#msg1308531 BkkCoins says he has an Electrum fork (https://github.com/bkkcoins) that allows it to support multiple exchanges. But be careful as reading later posts from Bkkcoins indicate that his fork may not be compatible with latest mainline Electrum build.

Comment: [MultiBit](http://multibit.org) uses the Java [XChange](https://github.com/timmolter/XChange) library which is able to work with multiple exchanges. It might be possible to leverage the code in that library in your own projects.